# What are namespaces for ? what about usages?

Tags: namespaces, clojure

1. what is the purpose of namespaces ?
2. and, more important, should they be used as objects in java (things that have data and functions and that try to achieve encapsulation) ? is this idea to far fetched ? :)
3. or should they be used as packages in java ?
4. or should they be used more generally as a module system or something ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given that you use the Clojure tag, I suppose that you'll be interested in a Clojure-specific answer:

> what is the purpose of namespaces ?

Clojure namespaces, Java packages, Haskell / Python / whatever modules... At a very high level, they're all different names for the same basic mechanism whose primary purpose is to prevent name clashes in non-trivial codebases. Of course, each solution has its own little twists and quirks which make sense in the context of a given language and would not make sense outside of it. The rest of this answer will deal with the twists and quirks specific to Clojure.

**A Clojure namespace groups Vars**, which are containers holding functions (most often), macro functions (functions used by the compiler to generate macroexpansions of appropriate forms, normally defined with `defmacro`; actually they are just regular Clojure functions, although there is some magic to the way in which they are registered with the compiler) and occasionally various "global parameters" (say, `clojure.core/*in*` for standard input), Atoms / Refs etc. The protocol facility introduced in Clojure 1.2 has the nice property that protocols are backed by Vars, as are the individual protocol functions; this is key to the way in which protocols present a solution to the expression problem (which is however probably out of the scope of this answer!).

It stands to reason that namespaces should group Vars which are somehow related. In general, creating a namespace is a quick & cheap operation, so it is perfectly fine (and indeed usual) to use a single namespace in early stages of development, then as independent chunks of functionality emerge, factor those out into their own namespaces, rinse & repeat... Only the things which are part of the public API need to be distributed between namespaces up front (or rather: prior to a stable release), since the fact that function such-and-such resides in namespace so-and-so is of course a part of the API.

> and, more important, should they be used as objects in java (things that have data and functions and that try to achieve encapsulation) ? is this idea to far fetched ? :)

Normally, the answer is no. You might get a picture not too far from the truth if you approach them as classes with lots of static methods, no instance methods, no public constructors and often no state (though occasionally there may be some "class data members" in the form of Vars holding Atoms / Refs); but arguably it may be more useful not to try to apply Java-ish metaphors to Clojure idioms and to approach a namespace as a group of functions etc. and not "a class holding a group of functions" or some such thing.

There is an important exception to this general rule: namespaces which include `:gen-class` in their `ns` form. These are meant precisely to implement a Java class which may later be instantiated, which might have instance methods and per-instance state etc. Note that `:gen-class` is an interop feature -- pure Clojure code should generally avoid it.

> or should they be used as packages in java ?

They serve some of the same purposes packages were designed to serve (as already mentioned above); the analogy, although it's certainly there, is not that useful, however, just because the things which packages group together (Java classes) are not at all like the things which Clojure namespaces group together (Clojure Vars), the various "access levels" (`private` / `package` / `public` in Java, `{:private true}` or not in Clojure) work very differently etc.

That being said, one has to remember that there is a certain correspondence between namespaces and packages / classes residing in particular packages. A namespace called `foo.bar`, when compiled, produces a class called `bar` in the package `foo`; this means, in particular, that namespace names should contain at least one dot, as so-called single-segment names apparently lead to classes being put in the "default package", leading to all sorts of weirdness. (E.g. I find it impossible to have VisualVM's profiler notice any functions defined in single-segment namespaces.)

Also, **`deftype` / `defrecord`-created types do not reside in namespaces**. A `(defrecord Foo [...] ...)` form in the file where namespace `foo.bar` is defined creates a class called `Foo` in the package `foo.bar`. To use the type `Foo` from another namespace, one would have to `:import` the class `Foo` from the `foo.bar` package -- `:use` / `:require` would not work, since they pull in Vars from namespaces, which records / types are not.

So, in this particular case, there is a certain correspondence between namespaces and packages which Clojure programmers who wish to take advantage of some of the newer language features need to be aware of. Some find that this gives an "interop flavour" to features which are not otherwise considered to belong in the realm of interop (`defrecord` / `deftype` / `defprotocol` are a good abstraction mechanism even if we forget about their role in achieving platform speed on the JVM) and it is certainly possible that in some future version of Clojure this flavour might be done away with, so that the namespace name / package name correspondence for `deftype` & Co. can be treated as an implementation detail.

> or should they be used more generally as a module system or something ?

They *are* a module system and this is indeed how they should be used.

Answer (score 2):

A package in Java has its own namespace, which provides a logical grouping of classes. It also helps prevent naming collisions. For example in java you will find java.util.Date and java.sql.Date - two different classes with the same name differentiated by their namespace. If you try an import both into a java file, you will see that it wont compile. At least one version will need to use its explicit namespace.

Answer (score 1):

From a language independant view, namespaces are a way to isolate things (i.e. encapsulate in a sens). It's a more general concept (see xml namespaces for example). You can "create" namespaces in several ways, depending on the language you use: packages, static classes, modules and so on. All of these provides namespaces to the objects/data/functions they contain. This allow to organize the code better, to isolate features, tends for better code reuse and adaptability (as encapsulation)
As stated in the "Zen of Python", "Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those !".

Answer (score 0):

Think of them as containers for your classes.  As in if you had a helper class for building strings and you wanted it in your business layer you would use a namespace such as MyApp.Business.Helpers.  This allows your classes to be contained in sensical locations so when you or some else referencing your code wants to cosume them they can be located easily.  For another example if you wanted to consume a SQL connection helper class you would probably use something like:

`MyApp.Data.SqlConnectionHelper sqlHelper = new MyApp.Data.SqlConnectionHelper();`

In reality you would use a "using" statement so you wouldn't need to fully qualify the namespace just to declare the variable.

Paul